# SQL: How to use comma values to join another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table `A`:

```
id  username  like_books 
-----------------------
1   Peter     1,2,3
2   John      1,2
```

Table `B`:

```
id  book_name  
-----------------------
1   Legend
2   StackOverFlow
3   Google
```

For now, 
Is there any sql statement that can show the output as below:

Output:

```
id username    like_books
------------------------------------
1  Peter       Legend,StackOverFlow,Google
2  John        Legend,StackOverFlow
```

Thanks.

Comment: @RahulTripathi MySQL

Comment: TableA: what's like_books column type?

Comment: You don't normally use a comma-separated list in a database field to join to another database field. Many values per field break the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Reasonable database designs usually replace it [with an additional table](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/).

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều VARCHAR(30)

Comment: @sirsince1990 Oh...my question is duplicate...

Comment: @9000 As you said, what is the better way for this case?

Comment: @user3789802: follow the second link. In your case I'd have table `user(id, name)`, table `book(id, name)` and table `user_likes_book(user_id foreign key user(id), book_id foreign key book(id))`. This is a classic [M:N or many-to-many relationship pattern](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html)

Comment: @9000 Roger that and thanks for your information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  a.id,a.username,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.book_name ORDER BY b.id) like_books
FROM    A a
INNER JOIN B b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.like_books) > 0
GROUP   BY a.id
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5da6e/1)**

Comment: What would be the query in SQL?

Comment: Thank you, it is work. But is there any better ways to design database and pattern? As @9000 said.

Comment: @Metaphor:- This is SQL only, which will work in MySQL database.

Comment: @RahulTripathi But, i've got error in SQL 2012.

Comment: There is nothing like SQL 2012. You might be trying in SQL Server...right?

Comment: good answer can you explain the query so that new learns like me can understand the flow.mainly GROUP_CONCAT,FIND_IN_SET?

Comment: Ya, SQL Server 2012. the error: 'GROUP_CONCAT is not a recognized function name'

Comment: @Metaphor:- Group_Concat is for MySQL. You can use STUFF function in SQL Server

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it.

Comment: @VigneswaranS:- You can refer: [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) Do let me know if you dont understand anything in it.

Comment: @Metaphor:- You are welcome!